# three.js object matrix JSON generation

Tags: javascript, json, matrix, three.js, geometry

I want to generate JSON for `three.js` to import. I'll be generating it in C# from my own geometry classes. `Three.js` has provided the [schema](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Object-Scene-format-4), but I'm uncertain of what the numbers in `jsonFormat4.object.children[1].matrix` in this example JSON mean. Here is the array at that path:

```
[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,100,200,150,1]
```

I have figured out some of the values by playing in the [editor](http://threejs.org/editor/) using File > Export Object. For example, value `jsonFormat4.object.children[1].matrix[13]` seems to be the x position, `jsonFormat4.object.children[1].matrix[14]` the y position, and `jsonFormat4.object.children[1].matrix[15]` the z position.

But I am wondering what the others are and if there is more comprehensive documentation on this (if not, perhaps this question could become that). How are the numbers at the other indices determined? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is column-major [transformation matrix](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/affine/matrix4x4/) of scene node relative to its parent node (and world transform in case of root). 3x3 upper-left submatrix represents rotation*scale and first 3 values of last column is a translation vector.

Answer (score -1):

Currently we only got this solved for rotation around z axis.  This is all I need but may be helpful to someone:

Z rotation (Ψ) = (180/π) * ATAN(matrix[0]/[matrix[1])

Scale X = matrix[0] / cos(Ψ)

Scale Y = matrix[5] / cos(Ψ)

Scale Z = matrix[10]

Where X and Y rotation is 0.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).